# Google Calendar API v3 - Persistent Authorization with Code

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Im wondering if anyone has any answers to this. If one follows the quickstart here:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/go

we can get authorization from a user that allows us to do things with their calendar.

It seems the HTTP Client given back from the config handles calling the refresh token and keeping the client up to date.

First, as a side-question, does anyone know how long this is allowed to persist? I read in a doc somewhere that for unpublished apps/projects its 7 days, but it didn't specify a timeline otherwise. Is it indefinite or will this expire at some point (ie the refresh token runs out after 30 days). And is this avoidable at all?

now, the real question - if you take the service down entirely, ie for an update, and restart it, is there any way to opick up the authorization again? In the tutorial its writing a code to disk and reading as needed. In my case I just hold reference to the things I need in the application, so obviously when the service went down id have to reauthorize. I then tried writing the code to disk on a persistent volume and re-reading from that, but it doesnt get authorized - I guess because the new instance of the service has a new instance of the oauth config, and it wont accept the old code perhaps?

In any case, im wondering if anyone knows of a way to make this persist through ssytem restarts, or if the only real option here is to move the calendar service client to a small microservice on the side that we do not restart, and contact it from elsewhere as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refresh tokens can [expire](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration). The doc's exceptions aside, in practice, ongoing use, will get refresh tokens (and access tokens) refreshed. It's generally undesirable to want very long-lived tokens.

Comment: The service is Google Calendar. Restarting your client, it should be able to continue using the persisted tokens (refreshing if needed). In fact, the sample completes and you should be able to rerun it without re-auth'ing. Do you experience different behavior?  `calendar.NewService` is poorly named, it's really a new client of the service.

Comment: If you're unaware of it, Google Workspace provides [Domain-wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) (using a Service Account) that's permitted to operate on behalf of a domain's users. This *may* be a more appropriate identity for your needs.

Comment: Hi, let me know if my answer helped you. If this answered your question you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so this can help other people in the community who may have the same concern as you.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh token expiration is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration). As you've noted, tokens expire in 7 days for projects in "Testing" status. Refresh tokens for projects in production last **indefinitely**, but there are some scenarios where they may get invalidated (user revokes access, token has not been used in 6 months, the account has over 50 live tokens, etc.). It's not mentioned but if you change your OAuth scopes you'll probably need to reauthorize as well.

This means that as long as you keep your refresh tokens and none of the invalidation conditions are met, you should be able to keep using them to get new access tokens even if your service goes down temporarily. But as mentioned in the documentation, you should anticipate the possibility that the token stops working and redirect the user to authorize again.

My guess is that in your case the refresh token stopped working for some reason (maybe the 7 days limit) and the application just tried to use the same expired token. The Quickstarts in Google's documentation usually handle the creation of the token file and how to reuse it, but they don't include the part where you have an invalid token and need to reauthorize.

##### References:

- [Google's OAuth2 Overview](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)
- [OAuth2 for Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)